# Excel VBA code to filter and then calculate ranges

Tags: excel, vba, loops, autofilter

A newbie to VBA, I created a MACRO that would filter the excel sheet and filter each group and then calculate their sums on sheet 2. Its working fine, except everytime the groups changes, I have to alter the codes since groups are hard coded.

Is there someway I can loop the groups (col2) so it will select all values present in that group (col 3) and perform sum function for each group?

Thanks so much for everyone's time!

```
Col 1   Col 2   Col 3
75524   F25-49  8
83992   P35+    1,047
67463   F25-54  3,983
117441  P25-54  313
105058  P25-54  -65
72744   P25-54  -18
73900   P25-54  122
```

Comment: It sounds like you should just use a pivot table or the sumif function

Answer (score 0):

Firstly add a reference to `Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime` in VBA >> Tools >> References. The below will then group the data in columns 2 and 3 and create a `Dictionary` with column 2 as the key and the sum as the value:

```
Dim dataGrouping As New Dictionary

Dim data As Variant

data = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(, 1)).Value

For i = 1 To UBound(data)

        If (dataGrouping.Exists(data(i, 1))) Then

            dataGrouping(data(i, 1)) = dataGrouping(data(i, 1)) + data(i, 2)

        Else

            dataGrouping.Add data(i, 1), data(i, 2)

        End If

Next i
```